# Html charset code in inline editor in datatables/editor

Tags: html, laravel, datatables, character-encoding, editor

I'm using datatables.net and its plugin Editor
I'm having trouble when i edit a field.

in edit field i've got 
L& #0039;ALSACE  instead of L'ALSACE

[image]

Instead of clean uft8 i've got an html encoded char.

What do i do wrong ?

Laravel is 6.5.0. 
MySQL db is utf8mb4, collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci; 
laravel database config file is well configured ('charset' => 'utf8mb4', 'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
Editor is version 1.9.2
Datatables is version 1.10.20
yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle             v9.7.1

Laravel controler (ajax get Json Data)

```
public function getList()
{
    $regie = Regie::select(['id','libelle','web'])
        ->where('typemedia_id', '=', 8)
        ->with('grouperegies');

        return Datatables::make($regie)->toJson();
 }
```

Laravel Blade (view) js part

```
var editor;
  $(document).ready( function () {
    editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
    ajax:  '{{ url('regiepqr-list') }}',
    table: '#laravel_datatable',
    idSrc:  'id',
    fields: [
        { label: 'id', name: 'id' }, 
          { label: 'libelle', name:'libelle'},
          { label: 'web', name:'web'}
    ]
} );
$('#laravel_datatable').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
        editor.inline( this );
    } );
$('#laravel_datatable').DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      responsive: true,
      select: true,
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
        { extend: 'create', editor: editor },
        { extend: 'edit',   editor: editor },
        { extend: 'remove', editor: editor }
    ],
      language: {"url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/French.json"},
      ajax: "{{ url('regiepqr-list') }}",
      columns: [
          { data: 'id' }, 
          { data: 'libelle'},
          { data: 'web' }
      ]
    });
  });
```

A dd( Datatables::make($regie)->toJson()) in my controler show me that data are already in html encode char. is it normal ?

Many thank's
B.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, the trouble seems to be with yajra/laravel-datatables
(any other laravel class work's fine).

I try to config vendor\yajra\laravel-datatables-oracle\src\config\datatables.php

```
'json' => [ 'header' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json;charset=utf8'], 'options' => JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES , ],
```

or

```
'header' => ['Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'],
```

but no success (the header change but not the JSON)

The workaround is to use ->rawColumns().

```
    return Datatables::of($regie)->rawColumns(['libelle'])->make(true);
```

It's working but it's not very convenient : i have to think about each column...
any other ideas ?
Thank's